# How to create a search option in Custom List View in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-toolbar, android-search

Look, My Android Activity parsing a list of data (Name, Address)  and showing it on listview.
What i am using in Activity those

```
 private List<RestListModel> rdataList= new ArrayList<RestListModel>();
  private ListView listView;
  private CustomListAdapter adapter;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quick_list);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);            

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rrlist);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, rdataList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
```

////Here is the search option code in Activity

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menutosearch, menu);

        final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        search = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();

        //*** setOnQueryTextListener ***
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

// And my Custom List adapter is like that.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<RestListModel> rItems;
        private ArrayList<RestListModel> arraylist;
        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<RestListModel> restItems) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.rItems = restItems;
            this.arraylist = new ArrayList<RestListModel>();
            this.arraylist.addAll(restItems);
        }
```

/// filter method code in CustomListAdapter

// Filter method

```
public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            rItems.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                rItems.addAll(arraylist);
            } else {
                for (RestListModel wp : arraylist) {
                    if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                            .contains(charText)) {
                        rItems.add(wp);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic adapter

Comment: Could you check it in this project ?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wimkimzcynxz18/CustomListViewVolley1.zip?dl=0

Comment: 1.16 MB ?? no, its too much, post your adapter source file only

Comment: Whole project is there .If you import it on Android Studio then could check it out.

Okay , Here is only MainActivity with adapter 
http://pastebin.com/4FUafUBw

Comment: there is no `MatchableArrayAdapter` in it, only `CustomListAdapter` extending `BaseAdapter`

Comment: Actually, I am looking to solve this problems,If you know Generic Adapter will work , could you change it for me? to my project

Comment: just use `MatchableArrayAdapter<Movie> adapter = new MatchableArrayAdapter<>(....);` you are passing `Movie` class array, arent you?

Comment: Okay.I am going to try it. But was wrong with my code?

Comment: it is too complex, use `MatchableArrayAdapter` and you will know why

Comment: here you have a [sample](http://pastebin.com/Dm94WW2G) code on how to filter out items

Comment: Could you do it on my code? Just import it on Android studio.I am not familiar with MatchableArrayAdapter. I think it will be easier for you

Comment: whats unclear with those 32 lines of code? just paste them in your Activity#onCreate method and play with it